# Add string before number in string

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for solutions.

I have string something like  `"AAAAAA 8 BBBBBB 5"`
I must replace space before numbers with `-`, and other space with `_-_`.

Can some one help  me.

Comment: so you need to [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REPLACE.html) a `' '`with a `'-' ` …

Comment: yes, but this is simple, i must find number in string, then add before number '-' and other spaces replace with   '\_-\_ '

Comment: i don't know how to find number in string and add '-' before it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it with 2 regexp_replace like so:

```
with the_string as (
    select 'AAAAAA 8 BBBBBB 5' s from dual
),
the_string_with_numbers_done as (
    select regexp_replace (s,' (\d)','-\1') s from the_string
)
select regexp_replace (s,' ','_-_') from the_string_with_numbers_done
;
```

Here is info on regexp_replace: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302

And this is the site I like to use to work on regular expressions: https://regexr.com/

**Edit:** Slightly changed version based on later comments from OP - for changed blank handling as OP seems to want to have successive blanks handled as one in some/all cases. The requirements are still not 100% clear to me though, especially what `blank blank number` should become: `dash number` or `underscore dash underscore dash number`. The below version does the former (`dash number`). HTH

```
with the_string as (
    select 'AAAAAA 8 BBBBBB 5' s from dual
),
the_string_with_numbers_done as (
    select regexp_replace (s,' +(\d)','-\1') s from the_string
)
select regexp_replace (s,' +','_-_') from the_string_with_numbers_done
;+
```

Comment: From Topcio's answer it seems there can be multiple spaces, so might be worth extending this answer with `' +'` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here.

Example:

```
select regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace('AAAAAA 8 BBBBBB 5', '\s([[:digit:]]+)', '-\1', 1, 0), 
                                               '([[:digit:]]+\s)', '\1_-_', 1, 0) as str
  from dual;

STR
--------------------
AAAAAA-8 _-_BBBBBB-5
```

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302

Comment: Barbaros - the question was about PL/SQL, but yes, this SQL revision is neat.

Answer (score 0):

I also added

```
with the_string as (
    select TEST s from AA_TEST
),
**multiple_spaces as (
  select regexp_replace (s, '\s{2,}', ' ') s from the_string
),**
the_string_with_numbers_done as (
    select regexp_replace (s,' (\d)','_\1') s from multiple_spaces
)
select regexp_replace (s,' ','_-_') from the_string_with_numbers_done
;
```

And now, everything work perfect

Comment: Wouldn't you just include the multiple space pattern in one of the existing regexes,rather than adding a whole new layer?

Comment: I think not, because everyone does something else, but I do not know so much, so I may be wrong